# How can I write a custom deleter for an array managed by an unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, destructor, unique-ptr

I am trying to find a way to write a custom deleter for a C array managed by a unique_ptr in a templated C++ class. I am purposefully trying to make the class leak memory by making the deleter do nothing. In the full class, some constructors allocate the memory and some do not - rather they make use of the memory in a raw byte buffer coming from a data stream.

This is what I tried:

```cpp
template <class T> class Matrix
{
    private:
    int _size;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> _array;

    public:
    Matrix(int size, void* data) : _size(size)
                                 , _array(NULL, [](T[]* p){})
    {
        _array.reset((T*)data);
    }
};
```

The code does not compile, the error message is:

```
In file included from /tmp/test/test/test.cpp:9:
/tmp/test/test/Matrix.h:22:55: error: expected ')'
                                 , _array(NULL, [](T[]* p){})
                                                      ^
/tmp/test/test/Matrix.h:22:51: note: to match this '('
                                 , _array(NULL, [](T[]* p){})
                                                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: "The code does not compile." What error do you get? Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58128286/edit) and copy the full error there?

Comment: Why would you like to have a unique_ptr when you don't want to delete the array? Could you not just use a raw pointer?

Comment: In the full class, some constructors allocate the memory and some do not - rather they make use of the memory in a raw byte buffer coming from a data stream. I only want the memory to be freed in the case that the constructor allocated that memory. Using a raw pointer and a flag to fork in the destructor would be easier but I have this problem in large classes and some APIs cannot be modified.

Comment: To supply a custom deleter, you need use the second template argument.   `std::unique_ptr<T[],   Deleter>`  where `Deleter` is the type of function (or object) that does the deleting.    Then the construction of the `unique_ptr` needs to pass a second argument, of that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, always create a simple setup to test things:

```
int main() {
    using T = int;

    std::unique_ptr<T[]> _array(NULL, [](T[]* p){});

    return 0;
}
```

So now to your problem:

- `T[]* p` is not valid and should be `T* p`.
- The lambda you pass as deleter does not match `std::default_delete<T>` which is used as default deleter.  So you have to write `std::unique_ptr<T[],std::function<void(T*)>`.
- And `NULL` might be implemented as an integral type, so you should use `nullptr` instead, otherwise `gcc` won't compile your code (since c++11 you, in general, should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`).

So putting everything together you get:

```
int main() {
    using T = int;

    std::unique_ptr<T[],std::function<void(T[])>> _array(nullptr, [](T* p){});

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The deleter is a template parameter of `std::unique_ptr`. By default it is `std::default_delete`, but you can specify something different, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct NonDeleter
{
    void operator()(T*) { /* nothing */ }
};

template <typename T>
struct NonDeleter<T[]> : NonDeleter<T> {};

template <class T> class Matrix
{
    private:
    int _size;
    std::unique_ptr<T[], NonDeleter<T[]>> _array;

    public:
    Matrix(int size, void* data) : _size(size)
                                 , _array(static_cast<T*>(data))
    {
    }
};
```